# Not able to add data for 50 users using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Executed load testing script using JMeter for 50 users but it is not adding data in database for 50 users and adding only for 20 users, What is the issue?

Comment: It is usually helpful to see some code. Could you show up what the insert logic looks like and the testing script?

Answer (score 0):

Open your [.jtl reusults file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) with a [listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and check the number of failures, if it's around 40% - then you need to investigate the cause of the failures and see what needs to be done to fix them either from JMeter or from application under test perspectives.

If there are no failures in the .jtl file but your test is not doing what it is supposed to be doing - most probably it "silently" fails somewhere somehow. I would recommend adding [Response Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to each and every step to validate that each response contains the anticipated data (or alternatively doesn't contain errors).

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful and doesn't do any other checks so in case when an error occurs but application responds with a positive HTTP status code JMeter will consider the request as passed so you need to specify pass/fail criteria.

And last but not the least, you can temporarily amend the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) so JMeter would store all the request/response details, after test run you will be able to examine the flows using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and identify where and how exactly your script does fail.

Comment: I have checked and validated the script, Script is correct, My issues is-> I have passed 50 users in file, so why all 50 users are not adding data and only 35 users are adding the data into application, Why there is inconsistency?